# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 1):

Since Alex is away, could I offer the following brief addition to his nomination (to be sportmanlike), please?

In general:

- Owner of the site's previous incarnation (SharePoint Overflow)
- Tireless dedication to the site's community and future
- Helped co-ordinate the site's transfer to SharePoint 2.0

Some specific examples of community guidance and dedication:

- The site's most [prolific editor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor)
- One of the most frequent voters (if not *the* most frequent) with over [2000 votes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/31/alex-angas)
- Either answered or asked (sometimes both) [pretty much every question on meta](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31/alex-angas)
- The only user to get the silver [SharePoint badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sharepoint) on StackOverflow

Comment: +1,000,000. I would add, he is the ONLY user to get the silver SharePoint badge on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sharepoint

Comment: @KitMenke: Added. Pretty impressive badge to get, to be fair.

Comment: Ok, this has been edited into Alex's nomination.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Thanks :)